# How to show nested pri files in project pane of Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, projects-and-solutions, qmake

I have a `.pri` file named `Deploy.pri` in my project `.pro` file.

Deploy.pri :

```
include(part1.pri)
include(part2.pri)
```

As you see it includes two other `.pri` files.

These pri files are displayed in Qt Creator project pane in the same level :

[image]

I want to know if there is any way to show them nested and in a hierarchical way like a tree?

Comment: AFAIK, the included .pri just work in that way.

Comment: Yes I wish at-least to find a workaround for this if there is no regular solution. This is so annoying. Consider that you have a `pri` file which contains a bunch of other pri files. When you include the pri, the project pane becomes populated by many pri files.

Comment: Hi Nejat, I organize my project using TEMPLATE = subdirs until the last pro/pri file where I have my sources. This works well, I have a perfect tree with Qt creator but you have to create your folders with your pro/pri files in the appropriate location.

Comment: @Martin I am afraid the `subdirs` template does not solve this problem. That's for the purpose of organizing project with sub projects. When you include such a pri file in one of the subprojects, again all of them are displayed in the same level.

Comment: Starting from Qt Creator 3.6 nested .pri files are shown in a tree: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-487

Answer (score 0):

First nest your modules into `subdirs`.

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS += project1 \
           project2
```

Then include `part1.pri` and `part2.pri` using `../` depending on the depth of your subdirectories like this 
`include(../part1.pri)`

Comment: It's obvious that `subdirs` projects are displayed in a hierarchical way. My question is how to show nested `.pri` files in a single `.pro` file. i.e how to show them hierarchical when you include one `.pri` file in another one.